# Laravel-Mongodb authentication always return false

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-authentication, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm using my own collection named **customer** instead of **users** in this case.

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $collection='customer';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Customer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('login', ["title" => "LOGIN"]);
    }

    public function validation(Request $request)
    {
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ])->onlyInput('email');
    }
}
```

**config/auth.php**

> 'providers' => [
> 'users' => [
> 'driver' => 'eloquent',
> 'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
> ],

**config/database.php**

> 'mongodb' => [
> 'driver' => 'mongodb',
> 'dsn' => env('DB_URI', 'mongodb://localhost:27017'),
> 'database' => 'herbal66',
> ],

**.env**

> DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
>  DB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017

It always return **'The provided credentials do not match our records.'**.
What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

In your `Customer` model, make sure you're using the `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model` class as the base class. Update your `use` statement like this:

```php
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

Also, ensure that the `email` field in the MongoDB collection is being stored as plain text (not hashed) since Laravel's default authentication expects the password to be hashed, but you're using MongoDB and might have different conventions.

If the issue persists, try debugging by checking if the email and password values are being fetched and passed correctly to the `Auth::attempt()` function.